# PDF file is asking me to UPLOAD another PDF file. What it can be?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, forms

I met a PDF file with a placeholder for a logo. When I click this placeholder, it is asking to "upload" a logo.

[image]

Pressing `Browse...` causes normal open file dialog appear, which is accepting only PDF files as input.

What it can be? Is it a script to upload logo to some web site? Or it is possible to "upload" data into standalone document and have it modified?

**UPDATE**

Incredible! I have uploaded my logo in PDF format and it looks like it was embedded into document. And document filesize became smaller!

Miracles!

Is this what is called "PDF forms" or what?

Comment: You tell us?  You have the actual document?  Is this behavior handled by Javascript, Flash, we can't tell you.  You need a PDF Editor to determine this.

Comment: I don't know what is it. If it is something custom then Ok. I was wondering, if this is conventional feature of PDF.

Comment: PDFS can contain any number of things. Uploading a logo isn't a standard feature of a PDF though.  In order to actually explain the behavior I have to know what sort of form element it is.